# BigMemory Go persistent diskstore uses huge amount of disk space

Tags: java, caching, ehcache-bigmemory

I am using Ehcache with BigMemory Go with a **local restartable persistent diskstore** for 6 caches. The cache configuration for each cache is as follows for each:

```
<cache name="CacheService"
   maxElementsInMemory="200000"
   eternal="false"
   timeToLiveSeconds="86400"
   statistics="true">
<persistence strategy="localRestartable"/>
<cacheEventListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"/>
</cache>
```

We know from profiling that the total in-memory size of all caches is less than 1GB. Yet, the persistent diskstore is currently using around 27GB of disk space. The 27GB consist of a number of seg*.frs files that are ~514MB in size. It seems these files are created every minute and then roll forward with files older than ~60min being deleted:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 jboss jboss    0 Nov 14 10:29 frs.backup.lck
-rw-r--r-- 1 jboss jboss    0 Nov 10 09:02 FRS.lck
-rw-r--r-- 1 jboss jboss 514M Nov 14 09:22 seg000013456.frs
-rw-r--r-- 1 jboss jboss 514M Nov 14 09:23 seg000013457.frs
-rw-r--r-- 1 jboss jboss 513M Nov 14 09:23 seg000013458.frs
...
-rw-r--r-- 1 jboss jboss 514M Nov 14 10:23 seg000013504.frs
-rw-r--r-- 1 jboss jboss 344M Nov 14 10:29 seg000013505.frs
```

My questions are:

- Is this expected behaviour for the diskstore? Or is there a problem
  with our caches/cache elements that generate a large amount of
  segments?
- Is there a way/configuration to limit the number of
  segments that are kept on disk?
- Or similarly decrease the 60 minute
  window to delete the files more frequently?

Comment: Other users with the [same problem](http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/8487.page)